# Django QuerySet with Models

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

I'm new to Django and trying to understand how to use querysets with models.

```
Model
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    accountid = models.CharField(max_length=34)

    def get_channel_list(self):
        return self.get_queryset().name()
```

What I want to do is return the entire name column as an array if account id matches. I'd like to use a function in the models.py but I haven't found an online sample that caters to what I'm looking for.

The above isn't returning any data even without a filter.

Any point in the right direction would be amazing.

Comment: do you want to return a name field value for an record with given accountid?

Comment: I want to return all name field values for all records with the given accountid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `objects.filter` and `classmethod`:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    accountid = models.CharField(max_length=34)

    @classmethod
    def get_channel_list(cls, acc):
        return cls.objects.filter(accountid=acc).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

There is another technique to do such things in django - define custom manager to model. (for example, you have several `Channel` models inherited from one base proxy model and you want to put same `get_channel_list` functions to some models - custom Manager is the way to go):

```
class ChannelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_channel_list(self, acc):
        return self.filter(accountid=acc).values_list('name', flat=True)

class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    accountid = models.CharField(max_length=34)

    objects = ChannelManager()
```

Comment: You could also use `self.objects.filter(accountid=self.accountid)`, since you're calling this as an instance method. If you don't do that, it might be purer design to declare the above as a class method.

Comment: How would I call this in a view? like I said, very new to Django. :\

Comment: Neither of these will work, as you can't access `objects`from an instance.

Comment: I think that he is looking for a static method, but of course +1 for an exact answer and for flat=True

Comment: I'm looking for it to be dynamic depending on whos logged in

Comment: @AndrewWilson just call Channel.get_channel_list(ACCOUNTID_YOU_NEED) and list with names will returned

Comment: You sir are the man, this works perfectly for what I need and I can expand off of this.

Comment: @ndpu I'm having troubles sorting by asc i'm using `return cls.objects.filter(accountid=account).order_by('-name').values_list('name', 'channelid')` It's listing them in this order
"TEST",
"B TEST",
"A TEST CHANNEL",
"A TEST CHANNEL",
"A TEST 2",
"A B TEST",
"TEST CHANNEL",
"TEST 3",
"TEST 3",
"TEST 2 CHANNEL"... Any thoughts?

Comment: figured out it's because it's case sensitive, hmmph. still stumped

Comment: Since it's really a new question, I posted it's own question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768955/django-query-sort-case-insensitive-using-model-method-with-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

You have failed to understand the difference between managers and models. It's the manager that it's responsible for creating queries, and which has the `get_queryset` method. From a model, you need to access the manager, which is usually named objects. Note, you cannot do that from an instance, so this needs to be a classmethod.

```
@classmethod
def get_channel_list(cls, accountid):
    return cls.objects.filter(accountid=accountid).values_list('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access the queryset/manager for a different reason, since google brought me here - this ended up my solution:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    accountid = models.CharField(max_length=34)

    def get_channel_list(cls, acc):
        return self.__class__.objects.filter(accountid=acc).values_list('name', flat=True)
```