# Django Query sort case-insensitive using Model method with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5, postgresql-9.3

I'm really new to django, python and postgres... I can't seem to find the answer on how to order_by being case insensitive while using Model as the query method, only if you use direct SQL queries.

```
Model
@classmethod
def get_channel_list(cls, account):
    return cls.objects.filter(accountid=account).order_by('-name').values_list('name', 'channelid')
```

Data set and order it's currently being ordered in

```
test
b test
a test channel
a test channel
a test 2 
a b test
Test Channel
Test 3
Test 3
Test 2 Channel
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`QuerySet.extra(select=...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
@classmethod
def get_channel_list(cls, account):
    ret = cls.objects.extra(select={'name_lower': 'lower(name)'})
    ret = ret.order_by('-name_lower')
    ret = ret.filter(accountid=account).values_list('name', 'channelid')
    return channels
```

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error `Cannot resolve keyword 'name_lower' into field. Choices are: accountid, active, channelid, id, name`

Comment: @AndrewWilson, You don't need to add extra field to the model. See [this screencast](http://asciinema.org/a/6905) I just recorded.

Comment: That for some reason doesn't work for me in Django 1.5.3 and Python 2.7, not sure if it's a version thing

Comment: @AndrewWilson, Try `select name from appname_modelname order by lower(name);` in `dbshell` . Does it work?

Comment: it returns the list of names without lowercasing the name in the correct order. Using Postgresql 9.3

Comment: @AndrewWilson, Is it what you want?

Comment: That is what I want from the DB Query, but it's not processing that list through my Model Query

Comment: @AndrewWilson, Using `Model.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appname_modelname ORDER BY LOWER(name)')` is not an option?

Comment: I believe it may be, is there any downfalls to not using the Django out of the box queries? (besides I'd get a functional response)?

Comment: @AndrewWilson, SQL version is more verbose, less compatible (because of usage of `lower` function, even though it is standard SQL function).

Comment: @AndrewWilson, BTW, if SQL does work, the code in the answer should also work. It's strange..

Comment: how would i reference the variable using .raw? currently I have `SELECT name, channelid, active FROM webapp_channel WHERE accountid=account ORDER BY LOWER(name)` but I don't know how to reference account as a python variable

Comment: @AndrewWilson, You can pass it as parameter: `Channel.objects.raw('SELECT name, channelid, active FROM webapp_channel WHERE accountid=? ORDER BY LOWER(name)', [account])`. I'm not sure `?` is correct placeholder (Right now I don't have access to postgresql). If it does not work try with `%s`.

Comment: @AndrewWilson, For more question, please post another question instead of extending comment.

Comment: Postgres may be a little different on what it's requiring. Here is how I fixed it `cursor = connection.cursor() cursor.execute('SELECT name, channelid, active, id FROM webapp_channel WHERE accountid=%s ORDER BY LOWER(name)', [name]) ret cursor.fetchall()` Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Update your answer to that so others can use it as a reference please

Answer (score 22):

With django 1.8, there is a built-in solution:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
...
ret = ret.order_by(Lower('name_lower'))
ret = ret.order_by(Lower('name_lower').asc())
ret = ret.order_by(Lower('name_lower').desc())
```

Comment: @Sven I would agree if my question wasn't specifically directed towards Django 1.5.3 (and not 1.8+)

Comment: This works when you're talking about sorting on just one column or multiple columns all in one direction. But, what if you need to sort multiple columns, some ascending and some descending?  (e.g. I'm selecting 4 columns and I want it sorted ascending by col 1 and, secondarily, descending by col 3)